# What is the most efficient way to mine DOGE?

Tags: dogeminer

So I recently stumbled upon this website (**be careful with the link, it has sound**), [dogeminer.se](http://dogeminer.se/), and it seems like a lot of (absosutely useless) fun. However I don't quite get what the most efficient way of mining is. When do I have to buy what miners?

Is it worth saving DOGE for a more expensive upgrade like the Moon Base? I saved up for a Space Rocket but it somehow didn't make too big of a difference.

Comment: Dear god what why

Comment: @Unionhawk because internet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way?

`window.setInterval(function(){$('#miner').trigger('mousedown')}, 1)`

Comment: How do you use this?

Comment: Ok nevermind I figured out. Just put it in the address bar. Wow. Very Work

Answer (score -3):

Go to settings
Click import save

- Enter This

***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***

Comment: And what does this do?